# Talend unknown server host name connection with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, talend, data-integration

I want to make talend metadata dbconnection with repository I have entered these as credentials

- Login: sa
- Password: ******
- Server: `Localhost\SQLEXPRESS`
- Port: 1433
- Database: mydb
- Additional Parameter: instance=SQLEXPRESS

but I get an error of unknown server host name `localhost\sqlexpress`, as I already connected to SQL Server Management Studio with these credentials.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly `Additional Parameter: instance=SQLEXPRESS` is redundant since you already have it in the Server parameter

Comment: yes i have tried empty additional parameter but having same issue

Comment: @HassanFarooq hallo farooq, did you manage to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I've the same problem and solved it doing (using the connection used at the topic as example) this way:

- Login: sa
- Password: ******
- Server: Localhost
- Port: 1433
- Database: mydb
- Additional Parameter: instance=SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

Unlike when using SQL Server Management Studio,  MS SQL Connections in TOS Data Integration go through JDBC.  So, the server (or  host)  must either be an IP address or a DNS address which resolves.

In your case, I believe use the tMSSqlConnection component and the host should just be "localhost".

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tMSSqlConnection